# Flutter - Show cursors after a programmatic text selection inside a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a way to show the cursors after a programmatic text selection in flutter.

Like here:

### My code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  ExampleActivity({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleActivity> createState() => _ExampleActivityState();
}

class _ExampleActivityState extends State<ExampleActivity> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller.text = "Lorem Ipsum " * 5;
    _controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 12, extentOffset: 23);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: null,
      autofocus: true,
      showCursor: true,
      expands: true,
      enableInteractiveSelection: true,
      toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
          copy: false, cut: false, paste: false, selectAll: false),
    )));
  }
}
```

---

### Actual display

[image: Actual display]

### Expected display

[image: Expected display]

Answer (score 0):

your problem solved on flutter 3.7.
you can fix that by updating your flutter SDK.
here a link you can see flutter 3.7 news
https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-7-38cbea71133c